# How to make a PDO query with dynamic OR conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a query made that fetch an item from `ac_product` as:

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare('SELECT * from ac_product where active = "1" and id = :id');
$STH->bindParam(':id', $value);
```

One of the columns named relationship contains 0-n other id's that needs to be fetched.

Today the solution is one-query-per-id and I would like to limit it to less or only one if possible.

consider e.g.

```
$row['relationship'] //is 2.3.4
$arrayRelationship = explode(".",$row['relationship']);
```

Is it possible, and if so how, to make an PDO OR condition query that can fetch n of related items?

Or is there a smooth way to compile n number of queries and to at least do them at once with beginTransaction and commit?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)(), this is actually a substitute for logical OR.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * from ac_product where active = "1" and id IN (:id)');
```